# scrollTo(x,y) is not working in a webview for android 4.4

Tags: android, scroll, android-webview, android-4.4-kitkat

I want to scrollTo the top using scrollTo(0,0) and it does not show the top position on android kitkat whereas it works well for android 4.3 and below. Any way around to scroll in android 4.4 webview

Comment: Can you upload the relevant code ?

Comment: scrollTo certainly works in the 4.4 WebView. Without specific details it's hard to say what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

In Kitkat, chromium browser is used and they have removed many features from webview. Some of these bugs have already been reported to Google. Check the link below:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62378

Comment: Yes I know many features have been removed in new chromium webview but  there must be a workaround for doing this in new webview. I am just trying to find the workaround for that.